# Annotation for Subclass

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to this annotation.Kindly help me out the below issue.

My scenerio is like I have BasicInfo(Super Class,it doesn't have table),Employee(table=EmployeeTable) and Managertable=ManagerTable).

Here "ReportedPerson" is the variable should be used in Manager only.ReportedPerson field should be in Superclass(Because I may extend this superclass in so many classes)

I don't want to use this variable in Employee.So to Override this variable,I gave annotation @Transient in Employee class and 
@Column(name = "ReportedPerson")in BasicInfo class.

But it is not working.Can u pls help me how to overide this variable in Employee class.

```
//Basic Info class(Super class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicInfo implements java.io.Serializable {       
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name = EMPTY_STRING;
    @Column(name = "age")
    protected Integer age = null; 
    @Column(name = "ReportedPerson")
    protected Integer ReportedPerson = null; 
}
//Employee class
@Entity
@Table (name ="EmployeeTable")
public class Employee extends BasicInfo{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmployeeID")
    private String Id;
    @Transient
    protected Integer ReportedPerson = null; 

}
//Manager class
@Entity
@Table (name ="ManagerTable")
public class Manager extends BasicInfo{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ManagerID")
    private String Id;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is create one more superClass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicManagerInfo extends BasicInfo implements java.io.Serializable {       
    @Column(name = "ReportedPerson")
    protected Integer ReportedPerson = null; 
}
```

and extends Manager from BasicManagerInfo, Employee from BasicInfo:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BasicInfo implements java.io.Serializable {       
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name = EMPTY_STRING;
    @Column(name = "age")
    protected Integer age = null; 
}

//Employee class
@Entity
@Table (name ="EmployeeTable")
public class Employee extends BasicInfo{
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmployeeID")
    private String Id;
}

//Manager class
@Entity
@Table (name ="ManagerTable")
public class Manager extends BasicManagerInfo{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ManagerID")
    private String Id;

}
```

Comment: @aleksi Actually The scenario is "ReportedPerson" variable should be in BasicInfo class.In Employee class,I need to use "ReportedPerson" 
as Transient attribute which only shown in GUI.No need to save in database.But in Manager class,it should save in database,so I extend from BasicInfo(In that
I gave annotation @Column).Suppose I make it as a seperate class,apprx I need to modify huge class.
So is there any possibility to override as Transient "ReportedPerson" variable in Employee class.